# Access joined fields in query result

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have a query with 2 Joins to other tables, the query executes and returns all the fields from the primary table but I am not sure how I can get access to the joined fields.

in func LastTest() I am setting the var **result** to the TestResultDetail table, I would also like access to TestResult and SeqTestStage values in my result which are joined in the query.

Post query I can access all of the result fields in the TestResult table but none of the tables I joined on.

TestResultDetail has a FK relation to TestResult.
There are many TestResultDetail records for a single TestResult record.

For example seq_test_stage.description or any field in seq_test_stage comes over as empty.

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "./models"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

func main() {
    router := gin.Default()

    opt := router.Group("opt/v2")
    {
        opt.GET("/ping", func(c *gin.Context) {
            c.String(200, "pong")
        })
        opt.GET("/last-completed-test/:serial", LastTest)
    }

    // Add API handlers here
    router.Run(":3000")
}

func LastTest(c *gin.Context) {
    // Connection to the database
    db := models.InitDB()
    defer db.Close()

    var result models.TestResultDetail

    type Response struct {
        Status   string
        Id   int64
        Serial   string
        Product  string
        Stage    string

    }

    // get param and query
    serial := c.Params.ByName("serial")
    db.Model(&models.TestResultDetail{}).
        Select("test_result.id, test_result.serial, test_result.product, test_result_detail.stage_id, seq_test_stage.description").
        Joins("join test_result on test_result.ID = test_result_detail.result_id").
        Joins("join seq_test_stage on seq_test_stage.ID = test_result_detail.stage_id").
        Where("test_result.serial = ?", serial).
        Order("test_result_detail.id desc").
        Limit(1).
        Scan(&result)

    if result.ID != 0 {
        res1 := &Response{
            Status: "OK",
            Id: result.ResultId.ID,
            Serial: result.ResultId.Serial,
            Product: result.ResultId.Product,
            Stage: result.StageId.Description,
        }

        c.JSON(200, res1)
    } else {
        // Display JSON error
        c.JSON(404, gin.H{"error": "No Records", "code": 404})
    }
}
```

**test_result_detail.go**

```
package models

import (
    "time"
)

type TestResultDetail struct {
    ID            int64 `gorm:"primary_key" db:"id" json:"id"`
    ResultId      TestResult
    StatusId      ResultStatus
    StationId     Station
    StageId       SeqTestStage
    OperatorId    AuthUser
    Failstep      string `db:"fail_step" json:"fail_step"`
    Shift         string `db:"shift" json:"shift"`
    SequenceRev   int `db:"sequence_rev" json:"sequence_rev"`
    DateAdded     time.Time `db:"date_added" json:"date_added"`
    DateTimestamp time.Time `db:"date_timestamp" json:"date_timestamp"`
    DateTime      time.Time `db:"date_time" json:"date_time"`
    StageOrder    int `db:"stage_order" json:"stage_order"`
    SerialNumber  string `db:"serial_number" json:"serial_number"`
    IsRetest      int `db:"is_retest" json:"is_retest"`
    RetestReason  string `db:"retest_reason" json:"retest_reason"`
}
```

**test_result.go**

```
package models

import (
    "time"
)

type TestResult struct {
    ID                    int64       `gorm:"primary_key" db:"id" json:"id"`
    DateAdded             time.Time `db:"date_added" json:"date_added"`
    Serial                string    `db:"serial" json:"serial"`
    SequenceId            int       `db:"sequence_id" json:"sequence_id"`
    LastCompletedStage    int       `db:"last_completed_stage" json:"last_completed_stage"`
    LastCompletedSequence int       `db:"last_completed_sequence" json:"last_completed_sequence"`
    Workorder             string    `db:"workorder" json:"workorder"`
    Product               string    `db:"product" json:"product"`
    IsComplete            string    `db:"is_complete" json:"is_complete"`
    IsScrapped            string    `db:"is_scrapped" json:"is_scrapped"`
    ValueStream           string    `db:"value_stream" json:"value_stream"`
    PromiseDate           string    `db:"promise_date" json:"promise_date"`
    FailLock              int       `db:"fail_lock" json:"fail_lock"`
    SequenceRev           int       `db:"sequence_rev" json:"sequence_rev"`
    DateUpdated           time.Time `db:"date_updated" json:"date_updated"`
    Date                  time.Time `db:"date" json:"date"`
    Time                  time.Time `db:"time" json:"time"`
    Ptyp2                 string    `db:"ptyp2" json:"ptyp2"`
    WoQty                 int       `db:"wo_qty" json:"wo_qty"`
    IsActive              int       `db:"is_active" json:"is_active"`
    IsTimeLock            int       `db:"is_time_lock" json:"is_time_lock"`
    TimeLockTimestamp     time.Time `db:"time_lock_timestamp" json:"time_lock_timestamp"`
    ScrapReason           string    `db:"scrap_reason" json:"scrap_reason"`
    ScrappedBy            int       `db:"scrapped_by" json:"scrapped_by"`
}
```

**seq_test_stage.go**

```
package models

import (
    "time"
)

type SeqTestStage struct {
    ID              int64 `gorm:"primary_key" db:"id" json:"id"`
    PdcptypeId      int `db:"pdcptype_id" json:"pdcptype"`
    Description     string `db:"description" json:"description"`
    LongDescription string `db:"long_description" json:"long_description"`
    IsActive        int `db:"is_active" json:"is_active"`
    DateAdded       time.Time `db:"date_added" json:"date_added"`
    DateUpdated     time.Time `db:"date_updated" json:"date_updated"`
    TimeLock        int `db:"time_lock" json:"time_lock"`
    LockMinutes     int `db:"lock_minutes" json:"lock_minutes"`
    LockHours       int `db:"lock_hours" json:"lock_hours"`
}
```

Comment: I believe you need to make another struct with the join relationships. This may help: https://kaviraj.me/go-gorm-using-joins/